# Counting the words in a paragraph using C

Tags: c

I wrote a program in C to count the number of words in a paragraph. On the terminal screen, it just takes one sentence as an input and then freezes. Any ideas why? I've tried other approaches and they work. Just want to know why this one doesn't.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(void)
{   int i, m=0, t=1;
    char x, a[100];
    clrscr();
    printf("Type a paragraph to count the words in it.\n");
    while(t==1)
    {   i=0;
        while(x!='\n')
        {   x=getchar();
            a[i]=x;
            i++;
            if((x==' ')||(x=='.')||(x=='?')||(x=='!'))
            m++;
        }

        if(a[0]=='\n')
        t=0;
    }
    printf("\nNumber of words = %i", m);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
The logic I've tried to use here is:
The inner loop takes in words upto 100 characters. Once a \n character is encountered, the loop is exited. The outer loop is there to extend the 100 character limit to an infinite number of characters(until the outer loop is exited). The outer loop is exited if a \n character is encountered in the first loop immediately after a previous loop is terminated with a \n. This implies that to end a paragraph, you need to type \n\n.

Comment: Side note: `if(a[0]=='\n')`?????

Comment: Also related: `while(x!='\n')` - look at that closely. On the initial entrance in to your outer loop, what value does `x` have? If your answer is "I dunno", you're in good company, because neither does your code.

Comment: @SamuelPeter You also need something to mark the end of a paragraph like a double \n  else it will be restricted to only one sentence.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does your "paragraph" have single-`'\n'` separating sentences, and a two consecutive `'\n'` terminating the paragraph? Or is it simply a string of words and punctuation until a single `'\n'` ? If the latter, this is fairly trivial. If the former, it gets a bit more complicated. An accurate description of what you mean by "paragraph" should be noted *in your question*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks a lot. I corrected that and now my code works just fine. Now I feel silly for not noticing that earlier.

Comment: I've tried to make it so that a single \n ends one sentence or a group of characters(upto 100). Another \n following the first, ends the paragraph and displays the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it exits the inner `while` loop, if `a[0]` isn't `\n`, then `t` will stay 1, but since `x` hasn't changed since it exited the inner loop, it won't re-enter it, so you stay stuck in the outer loop.